# Nest js Swagger UI not loading

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

in the browser I'm getting this error and the UI is not loading
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLLgl.png).

This is my swagger document config (main.ts)

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Truffles API')
  .setDescription('Truffles API description')
  .setVersion(DEFAULT_VERSION)
  .addTag('Truffles')
  .addBearerAuth()
  .build();

console.log(config);

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

SwaggerModule.setup(`${basePath}/docs`, app, document, {
  swaggerUrl: `${basePath}/docs-json`,
});
```